# trigger a autologon from computer startup script

Tags: windows, group-policy, startup-scripts

I am looking for a way, to automatically logon a User from computer startup script, without rebooting the machine. I know, I can write in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon... Keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) or use [Sysinternals autologon.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon), but this all don't work without a reboot.

OS: Windows >= 7

A while ago, I have seen a small until, who could do it. But I forgot about it and can't find it again. Or maybe there is any other solution?

I think, it is only possible with a [GINA plugin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/gina)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was that utility LogonExpert?

https://www.logonexpert.com/

There's a reference to it (and it was also marked as the solution) in the TechNet thread below.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/25677ebd-eb91-421e-9201-0e7fb69d46c0/force-autologon-directly-without-restart?forum=winservergen

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the tool I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully it is!

Answer (score 0):

After investigation of LogonExpert, I have now a idea, what need to be done. On Systems upwards Windows Vista, you need to build your own "[custom credential provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows), which replaces the GINA plugin".

A good reference to get a lot of information's and also running projects can be found on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/DavidWeiss2/windows-Credential-Provider-library).

At least, this question is also available on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687201/windows-7-login-script-using-password)...